# AngularJS directive not properly receiving link passed in attribute

Tags: angularjs

I've got an AngularJS directive that is not placing a string (intended to be a relative path to an image) inside one of the attributes in an HTML element and I'm at a loss as to why.

My item looks like the following:

```
item : {
  name: 'Test Name',
  link: 'Assets/logo.png'
}
```

If I step through the javascript, I'm correctly receiving the link from the webservice, so that's not the problem as my Angular controller properly shows the link in the $scope.

The following is what I have in the template for that controller that I'm having the problem with:

```
<my-directive name="{{item.name}}" link="{{item.link}}"></my-directive>
```

Here's the javascript for my directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/RelativePathToTemplateFile.html',
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attr, model) {
      $scope.name = attr.name;
      $scope.link = attr.link;
    }
  }
})
```

When I look at the rendered HTML, I have the following:

```
<div name="Test Name" link></div>
```

What's going on? How can I pass this link in properly?

Comment: where is the code for your directive?

Comment: can i see the content of the template? also why are you not using scope bindings instead of going to the attrs? and shouldn't it be my-directive in your marckup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive scope binding technique can resolve this issue. Try to use "@" to bind the directive property to the evaluated DOM attribute.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <my-directive my-name="{{item.name}}" my-link="{{item.link}}"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.item = {
    name:"Test Name",
    link:"Assets/logo.png"
  };
})
.directive("myDirective",function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div name="{{myName}}" link="{{myLink}}">{{myName}}</div>',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        myName:"@",
        myLink:"@"
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j78eU/2/), you could refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... } where:
* scope is an Angular scope object.
* element is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
* attrs is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding attribute values.
```

so it's "attrs", not "attr"

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
<myDirective name="item.name" link="item.link"></myDirective>
```

It will be better :)

Comment: Removing the curly braces would make any of the data bindings fail to work entirely.